# Accessing the URL in the Symfony 1.4 Task

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Our project have all the JSON webservices implemented in one module named webservice.

Now I have implemented one public method in this module which have no template. I have set this by using return sfView:NONE statement.

This public method can accessed through the url /cron. Basically it implements some algorithm as per our project requirement. This method needs no input parameter. 
This method can be accessed by the url as defined in the routing.yml.

Now I want to create the Symfony task which can hit this URL.

Help?

Comment: I'd be interested in some background info. Why do you need this to be accessed over HTTP? Can you not implement whatever logic is inside the action in the task? As tasks do not have the HTTP context, there is no way to know what the hostname is inside the task, unless you hardcode it.

Comment: @Gerry, can we move the code written the action to the  symfony task.

Comment: I haven't seen the code, but yes, you probably can.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you: http://www.symfony-project.org/cookbook/1_2/en/tasks

Its for Version 1.2, but most of the info is still valid.